# clojure resolving function from string name

Tags: clojure, eval

In clojure 1.2RC1, I wish to obtain a function based on its name as string and evaluate it.

Function definition

```
(ns my-ns)

(defn mycar [x] (first x))
```

The following worked:

```
((ns-resolve *ns* (symbol "mycar")) '(3 4))
((intern *ns* (symbol "mycar")) '(3 4))
((eval (symbol "mycar")) '(3  4))
```

but they seem ugly.  Is there a better way? If not, which of the above is the most idiomatic?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This worked for me without using eval:

```
user> (defn mycar [x] (first x))
#'user/mycar
user> ((resolve (symbol "mycar")) [1 2 3])
1
```

This works because resolves finds the mycar var in the current namespace and the var calls the function it's bound to. This is a shorter version of your first example. I'd use it just so that I could avoid using eval.

Comment: I second the use of `resolve` or `ns-resolve`. Also pay close attention when using `intern`. It's quite is to clobber things using it.

Comment: Any pointers to more information on "clobbering" caused by intern?

Comment: <del>Set a Var with intern and your original meta data on the Var will be gone.</del> Ignore. Seems to be fixed. At least I can't reproduce it anymore.

Comment: Thank you, Rayne. We miss you.